# Microcontroller DC analysis Voh(min) from the datasheet

Tags: microcontroller, digital-logic, ethernet, interface

I am doing the DC analysis of my Ethernet interface.

Interfacing [SAMA5D2](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/MPU32/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/SAMA5D2-Series-Datasheet-ds60001476.pdf) with [FS32K148HAT0MLUT](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/S32K-DS.pdf). This is a mac to mac communication.

In the datasheet of FS32K148HAT0MLUT Voh(min) value is not available. From the GPIO spec:

I believe Voh(max) of FS32K148HAT0MLUT is VDD-0.8.

May I know where I can get the Voh(min) of FS32K148HAT0MLUT.

[image]

Comment: Why do you believe VDD-0.8V is Voh(max)? It would mean for logic high all values up to VDD-0.8V are possible and values above VDD-0.8V are not possible. What sense that would make?

Comment: That is from the uC datasheet page no 32 ,Table 20 row 6

Comment: I can see that, but you don't 
answer my question.

Comment: Voh(Max) can come upto Vdd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A datasheet can specify either the minimum V<sub>OH</sub> at a certain test current, or the minimum I<sub>OH</sub> at a certain test voltage.

The FS32K148HAT0MLUT datasheet uses the second choice. That test voltage (V<sub>DD</sub> − 0.8 V) indeed is V<sub>OH(min)</sub>.

(And you should run both chips at 3.3 V.)